# Laravel 5.5 many to many relationship with an intermediate table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Please help,

I have these relationship in laravel between `ITEMS, SUPPLIERS and PURCHASE_ORDERS`

As `ITEMS` and `SUPPLIERS` has many to many relationship, I created an intermediate table between them, called `ITEM_SUPPLIER`.

Now I need to make a many to many relationship between `PURCHASE_ORDERS` and the intermediate table `ITEM_SUPPLIER`.

How do I make the relationship?
Should I create an intermediate table between them, what's the best way to name it?

Comment: Did you check answers ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got the time to continue working on my project. I got it working now thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a model for pivot table `ItemSupplier` whth extra column `id` which extends **Pivot**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ItemSupplier extends Pivot
{

    public function purchaseOrder()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(PURCHASE_ORDERS::class, item_supplier_purchase_order);
    }

}
```

As you see you need to create a new `item_supplier_purchase_order` pivot table and add the relationships

```
class PURCHASE_ORDERS extends Model
{

    public function purchaseOrder()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(ItemSupplier::class, item_supplier_purchase_order);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` column to the `item_supplier` and create `ItemSupplier` model for the pivot table. Then create a new `item_supplier_purchase_order` pivot table and two `belongsToMany()` relationships between `ItemSupplier` and `PurchaseOrder` models.

Also, don't forget to use [cascade deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) to delete records from new pivot table when a related record is deleted from `item_supplier` pivot table.